# Create Dummy variables work around

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create dummy variables from a column with pd.get_dummies or Serie.get_dummies but I get an instant error of Memory Error. (I have about 1 million rows).

the column looks like this:

```
      Col1
0     A | B
1       A
2     C | A
3     B | C
```

Is there any way to bypass this error ? using another library or something ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: You could buy more RAM. Or maybe just process small chunks at a time

Comment: As @djk47463 said, you should proceed line by line in two passes. First pass will collect all the values in the specified column, and then second pass will change the data according to the value in that column and write to a new file. After the new file is made, try to load it in sparse arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in trying other methods to encode your variables as [mentioned here](http://www.willmcginnis.com/2015/11/29/beyond-one-hot-an-exploration-of-categorical-variables/). You can also check out [this repository](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/categorical-encoding) for implementation of various methods mentioned in the article. Here is the [documentation for the same](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/).

Otherwise, you will have to do it in two passes as mentioned by @Vivek Kumar in his comment.

You can check out [this](http://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html) , [this](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2017/04/encoding-categorical-variables-one-hot-and-beyond/) and [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#feature-hashing) for more info on alternate methods of encoding variables.